# shmmax and shmall values in /etc/sysctl.conf are not loaded on reboot

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm running OSX 10.8.4 and I would like to add a factor of 10 to the default shmmax and shmall values. My `/etc/sysctl.conf` contains the following settings:

```
kern.sysv.shmmax=41943040
kern.sysv.shmmin=1
kern.sysv.shmmni=32
kern.sysv.shmseg=8
kern.sysv.shmall=10240
```

However when I reboot and run `sysctl -a | grep kern.sysv.shm` I see that the values are not being set:

```
kern.sysv.shmmax: 4194304
kern.sysv.shmmin: 1
kern.sysv.shmmni: 32
kern.sysv.shmseg: 8
kern.sysv.shmall: 1024
```

It seems the only way to be sure these are set is to run sysctl like so:

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmall=10240
sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmax=41943040
```

However I would like to automatically set these values on reboot if possible.

Am I missing some configuration step?

Also - Not sure if this matters, but I have installed postgres via homebrew.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same problem. Really inconvenient for development :(

Comment: Ah, good to know someone else has come across this issue. When I created this post I did not see many other people complaining about it. Still have not found a solution on my end.

Comment: Yeah, upgrading to PostgreSQL 9.3 renders this point moot, since they changed the memory architecture.